# Marking custom functions as step-over

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have some functions that the debugger should not step into when I press F8.

For example, I have a sub like this

```
DoSomething(DoThis(), DoThat())
```

Now when the I set a break point in this line, and I press F8, I would like to the debugger to NOT step into "DoThis", but it should step into "DoThat".

Is there a way to mark specific functions in a such a way that the debugger will skip stepping into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just give it the DebuggerStepThrough attribute like this

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
Private Sub DoThis()
   ...
End Sub
```